# What is this thing over my colony?

Tags: fragile-allegiance

I just started playing Fragile Allegiance and I switched to the orbit view of my colony, and noticed this big black diamond-shaped thing slowly float down into view.  Nothing happens when I click on it.  What is it??

[image: Black diamond thing]

Answer (score 1):

OK it turns out it was the space dock, which was under construction.  Once construction is finished, the look of it changes and you can click on it to build bigger ships.